# Object library changes using XCode 4 and storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, object, button, storyboard

When working in the .h or .m of my iPhone app in XCode, the Object Library contains a lot of nice buttons and stuff, i.e. a checkbox, which I would like to add to the interface. But when I enter the storyboard, it changes to just "Objects" and many of the buttons are replaced with view controllers and other stuff. How can I find the Object Library with all the buttons in my storyboard? I wanna add some checkboxes etc in my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See when you are working in .h and .m the object library shows all the stuff of iPhone/iPad and Mac.but when you open storyboard for iPhone/iPad all the stuff regarding Mac development is gone ,only the stuff relevant to iPhone/iPad is shown.